# TypeError: src is not a numpy array, neither a scalar

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, numpy, image-processing

```
    gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(contrast, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

TypeError: src is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
```

I am currently working to solve this, any help would be appreciated. As mentioned in the comments, the PIL image needs to be converted to CV2 accepted format, can anyone provide an explanation using the example given below?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from cycler import cycler
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance

# Loads the image then enhances it
image = Image.open('lineCapture.png')
contrast = ImageEnhance.Contrast(image)

# Reads the enhanced image and converts it to grayscale, creates new file
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(contrast, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) //there is a problem here
cv2.imwrite('enhancedGrayscaleLineCapture.png', gray_image)

# Adaptive Gaussian Thresholding
th1 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray_image,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,\
        cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
# Otsu's thresholding
ret2,th2 = cv2.threshold(gray_image,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
# Otsu's thresholding after Gaussian filtering
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray_image,(5,5),0)
ret3,th3 = cv2.threshold(blur,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# writes enhanced and thresholded img
cv2.imwrite('enhancedGrayscaleThresholdLineCapture.png', th2)
```

Comment: If you want to see the thresholded image, change to this, the writing in final image.
cv2.imwrite('enhancedGrayscaleThresholdCapture.png', th2)

Comment: @I.Newton thanks mate

Comment: @I.Newton how do i control the amount of image writing going on here? When I execute I write 3 files to the disk that I don't really need. I only need the final enhanced capture.

Comment: you need to put a hash tag infront of the imwrite, imread statements and pass the image variable to the next step instead of reading.

Comment: @I.Newton it looks like I am already doing that, example: ret2,th2 = cv2.threshold(img,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU) .... wouldn't image be an example of passing down that variable? img is the variable we are changing. So if I comment out the reads and writes it should just work internally until the final write?

Comment: ya, same for the ones on top. Ok, i'll post code changes in the answer, use that.

Comment: @I.Newton I will give you the check, thanks for your help.

Comment: @I.Newton File "C:\Automation\OCR\images\OCR_Preprocessing_Grayscale.py", line 18, in <module>
    gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(contrast, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
TypeError: src is not a numpy array, neither a scalar ... i will update code in post

Comment: @I.Newton the src "contrast" in the linementioned above seems to be the problem. Src needs to be an 8-bit unsigned, 16-bit unsigned ( CV_16UC... ), or single-precision floating-point. (http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html)

Comment: Oh sorry, you need to convert the PIL Image into cv2 format. Now i really dont know that. Good that you edited the question. I'll wait for the answer too.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

PIL is almost completely object oriented, so most functions return objects.

For example:

```
>>> image = Image.open('img6.png')
>>> type(image)
<class 'PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile'>
```

The PIL `Image` is a class (hence the capital) so it returns an object. So if the image is an object, it probably has properties, like the image data, the height/width of the image, and so on, along with built-in methods, like `.show()` which will display the image. You can [read the docs for the PIL `Image` class](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html) for more.

So you're passing classes along to functions which expect arrays. Going to have a problem there. One way to solve this is to read the data into a numpy array using [`image.getdata()`](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.getdata), which is the usual way to access pixel values in PIL.

**However**, numpy will automagically convert the `Image` into an array for you with a simple command: `np.asarray()`.

```
>>> image = Image.open('img6.png')
>>> type(image)
<class 'PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile'>
>>> image_data = np.asarray(image)
>>> type(image_data)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Yay! Now we have an array from the image. Importantly though, PIL reads images as RGB images like most other libraries, but OpenCV actually uses BGR channel ordering. So you'll need to make sure you swap the first and last channels around if you're going to use OpenCV to write, display, or modify images in a way that depends on their color.

Only one problem left...dealing with the contrast adjustment. `Contrast` from the `ImageEnhance` module returns an object as well:

```
>>> contrast = ImageEnhance.Contrast(image)
>>> type(contrast)
<class 'PIL.ImageEnhance.Contrast'>
```

But this returns a `Contrast` object, and not an `Image` object. In fact your code hasn't even modified the image; all you have done is create the enhancer object. You have to call a method to actually perform the contrast adjustment (and a factor of how strong you want it to be). Check the [docs for ImageEnhance](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/ImageEnhance.html):

> All enhancement classes implement a common interface, containing a single method:
>
> `enhance(factor)`
>
> Returns an enhanced image.
>
> **Parameters:** `factor` – A floating point value controlling the enhancement. Factor 1.0 always returns a copy of the original image, lower factors mean less color (brightness, contrast, etc), and higher values more. There are no restrictions on this value.
>
> **Return type:** `Image`

Now, *this* method returns an `Image`, so we can run `np.asarray()` on the result. So the final pipeline would be something like:

1. Load image into `Image` class
2. Create contrast enhancement object
3. Invoke `enhance(factor)` on the contrast enhancement object and the return val will be another `Image` class
4. Get a numpy array of the contrast adjusted image data
5. Convert from RGB to BGR order
6. Use normally

---

Input Image:

[image: Input image]

```
>>> pil_image = Image.open('img6.png')
>>> contrast_enhancer = ImageEnhance.Contrast(pil_image)
>>> pil_enhanced_image = contrast_enhancer.enhance(2)
>>> enhanced_image = np.asarray(pil_enhanced_image)
>>> r, g, b = cv2.split(enhanced_image)
>>> enhanced_image = cv2.merge([b, g, r])
>>> cv2.imshow('Enhanced Image', enhanced_image)
>>> cv2.waitKey()
```

Output Image:

[image: Contrast Enhanced Image]

Comment: there's a lot of information here about how I can better implement the color enhancer (thank you very much), but as far as the root problem goes, I am still pondering what I've done wrong with grayscaling the image after enhancement. @AlexanderReynolds

Comment: also I'm getting syntax errors regarding <class 'PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile'> @AlexanderReynolds

Comment: Accept this as answer @lizardwizard

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds Hello, thanks for helping me. I have one more question. I have a second piece of code that instead of grayscaling, it is an RBG image. r, g, b, a = cv2.split(img) returns an error of: <module>
    r, g, b, a = cv2.split(img)
ValueError: need more than 3 values to unpack. What would cause something like this?

Comment: Okay, did that, next issue = <module>
    cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
error: C:\build\master_winpack-bindings-win32-vc14-static\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\thresh.cpp:1446: error: (-215) src.type() == CV_8UC1 in function cv::adaptiveThreshold ... it has a problem with img, should this be something different, such as r,g,b or contrast? Also, why is this RBG cv2.split = r,g,b -- and the grayscale enhancer = r,g,b,a=cv2.split? @I.Newton

Comment: @lizardwizard the `split` and `merge` were to re-order the channels. The image taken from `np.asarray(pil_image)` is in RGB order, so we split and save each channel into the `r, g, b`. Then to get them in BGR order, we merge them in the opposite order; `b, g, r`. I don't know how PIL stores the alpha channel in a transparent PNG but it looks like Newton got it sorted out for you.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Alexander Reynolds for the great explanation. lizardwizard, since you are not able to figure out the mistake in your code, check this out

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from cycler import cycler
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance

# Loads the image then enhances it
image = Image.open('lineCapture.png')
contrast = ImageEnhance.Contrast(image)
img=contrast.enhance(2)
img = np.asarray(img)
r, g, b,a = cv2.split(img)
contrast=cv2.merge([b, g, r])
# Reads the enhanced image and converts it to grayscale, creates new file
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(contrast, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) #there is a problem here


# Adaptive Gaussian Thresholding
th1 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray_image,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,\
        cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
# Otsu's thresholding
ret2,th2 = cv2.threshold(th1,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
# Otsu's thresholding after Gaussian filtering
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(th2,(5,5),0)
ret3,th3 = cv2.threshold(blur,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# writes enhanced and thresholded img
cv2.imwrite('enhancedGrayscaleThresholdLineCapture.png', th3)
```

Comment: I now see the error of my ways! Contrast had to be vastly updated lol Thanks for your help in these endevours

Comment: Thanks for the add-on and continuing to support OP.